# Is it possible for Firestore to send a notification to my app when a date that I saved as a timestamp in my database is approaching?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Android app where people are supposed to post events. Obviously, every event has a "date" field with Timestamp value. I would like Firestore to notify the user that posted the event 30 minutes before it's set date, even if the user's not using the app at that moment.

Comment: If you want the user of the app to get notifications based on the events they have created, then you do not need to use **`Push Notifications`**. You can simply achieve that by using **`AlarmManager`**.

Answer (score 3):

Firestore doesn't have any ability to schedule work to happen in the future.  You could do this with a combination of Cloud Functions (to run code on the backend) and Cloud Tasks (to schedule to execution of the function in the future).  It's a non-trivial amount of work.  I suggest reading [this post about scheduling thing in the future](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a) with a combination of these three products.